# IntelliJ 15 - How use Mac native file path browser?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

How does one configure IntelliJ 15 to use the Mac native file path browser (for selecting files) rather than the IntelliJ file browser? I am using IntelliJ 15.0.1 and Mac OS 10.11.1.
Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Follow these steps to enable the native OS X file chooser in IntelliJ:

- Either use the top-level Menu: **Help** -> **Find Action...** ; Or Hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- Search for *Registry...*
- Find `ide.mac.file.chooser.native` key and set its value to true using the checkbox next to it

---

[image: Registry screenshot]

Comment: I was looking for something opposite - how to use IDE's dialog and not native. Either way, this answers helps. Thanks :)

Comment: What about linux